# Change the default editor when sudo visudo

Tags: vim, default-programs, nano, visudo

When doing `sudo visudo`, the default editor is `nano`.
I want to change it to `vi` or `vim`.

I already made `vim` the default editor, and use it as a substitute for `gedit` to open php, .txt, .c and .h files, by placing a `vim.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` and by correctly editing either  `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` or `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`. However apparently this does not apply to `nano`.

Any clue ?

Comment: Hve you checked `man visudo`?

Comment: I have found out some more things since I wrote it - I hope to add more later; The Linux distrbutions handle it differently.

Comment: Yes and I set my env-var VISUAL to vim and "exported" in .bashrc and in .bash_profile and then sourced the shell but to no avail. Even logged out and relogged-in in session to make sure.

Comment: I added the `sudo -E visudo` later in the answer, did you try that? The -E makes `sudo` not remove all env vars. It does because ubuntu has a line `Defaults env_reset` in `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Also, did you try the `update-alternatives` I also added?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/539243/how-to-change-visudo-editor-from-nano-to-vim has more upvotes for the question/accepted-answer... (as of this date-time: 31 upvotes vs 16 for this question).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: I don't understand yr comment. The other post is indeed a dupe. It came significantly after this one and its author should have consulted AU and other sources before posting. So should have all those who provided answers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is not that it does not apply to `nano`, it's that it does not apply to the shell:

Just set the `VISUAL` environment variable:

```
export VISUAL=vim
```

Add this too ~/.bashrc to make it permanent.

As you seem to use vim in general, set both `VISUAL` and `EDITOR`:

```
export VISUAL="vim"
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
```

or more POSIX-correct

```
VISUAL="vim" ; export VISUAL
EDITOR="$VISUAL" ; export EDITOR
```

I assume `nano` was the value of one or both variables.

To make use of the editor in visudo actually, we need to handle that `sudo` does not keep the environment variables by normally. The option `-E` changes that.

```
sudo -E visudo
```

Without the `-E` here, you would end up with a default of `nano` again

The two variables where in use long before files named `*.desktop` or `mime*` even existed.
(And the impressive thing is: they were actually used as a **common** standard.)
In Ubuntu, the system default seems to be set with `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`. It shows a menu to change the current association.

See section `ENVIRONMENT` in [`man visudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/visudo.8.html):

```
  VISUAL           Invoked by visudo as the editor to use

  EDITOR           Used by visudo if VISUAL is not set
```

Comment: Did you try it? By default `sudo` unsets most environment variables from the environment for the command it runs. `VISUAL=vim sudo visudo` (and the variations you suggest) doesn't work for me and shouldn't be expected to work. `sudo VISUAL=vim visudo` does work, though. (I've just tried both again, to be sure.) By the way, `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` are unset by default, not set to `nano`. `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` aren't the mechanism through which `visudo` selects `nano` in the default configuration (except insofar as it consults them, finds they're unset or blank, and moves on).

Comment: It works with `sudo -E visudo` - which should certainly be in the answer, right.

Comment: +1 and I do accept yr excellent answer, Volker. "Besten Dank !" I still got an error message with the -E flag, about not being allowed to pass on environment variables, but then I su'ed from a restricted access user to one with admin-privilege and bingo ! All works well.

Comment: Oh, I'm happy to add one more thing that can go wrong/can help ;) Could you check the options (lines with `Default` ) in your /etc/sudoers? I think there is an option that forbids that, but is was not in my default file.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: I imagine that you refer to the _env_reset_ default in _/etc/sudoers_. It is set just so in my case.

Comment: doesn't this create a security hole as per the visudo man page? `Note that this can be a security hole since it allows the user to execute any program they wish simply by setting VISUAL or EDITOR.`

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: Notwithstanding the potential security implications (though do they really matter, if the user can sudo at all to run visudo?), I might even suggest moving that reference to `sudo -E visudo` up to the top, for the many users who will have already tried setting `EDITOR` and/or `VISUAL` and/or even `SUDO_EDITOR`, and just wondering why it's not working.  Though the `update-alternatives` option is also quite nice, as then none of the rest matters.  :)

Comment: the right answer is: Defaults    editor=/usr/bin/vim

Answer (score 13):

If you never plan to use nano, you can also simply remove it. Then the system will use vi/vim as the default.

```
sudo apt-get purge nano
```

I know it is not the official answer, but it is one of the first commands for me after installing Ubuntu.

Comment: This definitely qualifies as "necroposting", but hey ... Yr answer is interesting, inasmuch it deals with Ubuntu. Some other distros (ArchLinux among them) only have the editor(s) you installed in the 1st place, so you have neither the pbm I encountered with Ubuntu, nor the need to resort to the measure you suggest. In the case at hand (ubuntu + nano + vim), I feel that many may have a need for options in terms of editors. It's true one rarely see the likes of `emacs` and `vim` actively coexist on any one user's profile. However `nano` and `vim` do happen together in the wild... Keep `nano` !

Comment: definitely the best answer

Comment: `emacs` and `vim` do happily coexist and are constantly used. `nano` is just like the pest, the sooner it is removed from the system the better. I do understand that some people may find it comfortable, but this answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: Maybe this works because when you remove nano, this happens ```update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vim.basic to provide /usr/bin/editor (editor) in auto mode```

Comment: Oh, this answer already exists :D

Answer (score 9):

As described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4409/103980), add

```
Defaults editor=/path/to/editor
```

to the [sudoers file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).

Note: this will only work if the file being edited contains the `Defaults editor=/path/to/editor` line or includes a file that contains it.

For example: `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/my_sudoers_extension` will default to Nano.

Comment: +1: Good one, and I had not noticed it when I first started this thread, thanks.

Comment: On macOS you can just comment out a line in the sudoers file instead of adding a new "Defaults" line.
`#Defaults       env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"`
This allows you to choose when launching visudo which editor:
`sudo EDITOR=/path/to/editor visudo`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using:

```
export VISUAL="vim"
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
```

Is that `sudo visudo` will sanitize the users environment variables so those variables are set in the root environment. If you are the only user of the machine (or everyone prefers VIM) you could always set those into root's environment too.