# How to change visudo editor from nano to vim?

Tags: command-line, vim, editor, nano, visudo

When I use `visudo`, it always opens it with `nano` editor. How to change the editor to vim?

Comment: My favorite method: get rid of nano: `sudo apt purge nano`. From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/994818/628938) in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Sheesh. It's so hard to figure out how to exit Nano, with the additional risk of writing the file. I can't even seem to manage consecutive undo! Please bring back Vim. It's much easier.

Answer (score 305):

Type `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`

You will get a text like below.

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
```

Find `vim.basic` or `vim.tiny` selection number. Type it and press enter. Next time when you open `visudo` your editor will be `vim`

Comment: What's the difference between `vim.basic` and `vim.tiny`?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/483308/what-are-the-differences-between-vim-basic-and-vim-tiny might answer you. check this also http://askubuntu.com/questions/104138/what-features-does-vim-tiny-have

Comment: `sudo EDITOR=vim visudo` is the way to go if you do not want to change the configuration permanently (see an another answer [below](https://askubuntu.com/a/539265/323249)).

Comment: This solution is not correct for the original question, because only address the problem in the Ubuntu/Debian case. The response should be for every (or at least the majority) of the posix compliant Linux systems, and at least one the responses below is more close to this target.

Answer (score 72):

If you want just to make your *user* use by default a different editor, add

```
export EDITOR=vim;
```

in your `.profile` (or wherever you keep your startup environment if using a shell different from bash). Log out, log in, check that the variable is set:

```
[romano:~] % env | grep EDI
EDITOR=vim
```

and now all the programs that call an editor (and are well written) will default to `vim` for your user.

As noticed by @EliahKagan (thanks!) in the comment, this will not work for `visudo`: since you are supposed to call it using `sudo`, when you do

```
sudo visudo
```

the `sudo` command will sanitize (read: delete) most environment variables before rising privileges --- and it's a good thing it does. So the change will not percolate to `visudo`. To still have it working, you have to call it like:

```
sudo EDITOR=vim visudo
```

Finally, as hinted here, you can also add a line to your `/etc/sudoers` file near the top that reads:

```
Defaults editor=/usr/bin/vim
```

A word of warning: when modifying your `sudoers` configuration, keep a terminal open with a root shell in it (with `sudo -i`). You never know, and you can easily get locked out of root.

Comment: Did you try this out? Running `sudo visudo` after setting `EDITOR` (or `VISUAL`) to `vim` and exporting it does not--and should not be expected to--result in `visudo` using `vim` instead of `nano` as the editor. By default, `sudo` resets most environment variables for the commands it runs. Only a handful are retained. `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` are not. Thus, after `export EDITOR=vim`, `EDITOR` will still not be set to `vim` for the `visudo` process launched by `sudo visudo`. `EDITOR=vim sudo visudo` does the same thing and thus also doesn't work. `sudo EDITOR=vim visudo` does work.

Comment: ...@EliahKagan, you are obviously right. I was thinking in deleting the answer, but your added information is valuable, so I tried to retain it somehow.

Comment: @EliahKagan ...and I know from where come my confusion... look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4409/52205 --- seems that, once upon a time, `sudo` did pass the EDITOR variable.

Comment: @Rmano it's not "once upon a time" exactly, but depends on what flags `visudo` was compiled and what options are set in `sudoers`.

Comment: doesn't using the EDITOR variable create a security hole as in the man page of visudo? `Note that this can be a security hole since it allows the user to execute any program they wish simply by setting VISUAL or EDITOR.`

Comment: I give an extra point to this response because it doesn't only gives a solution using a tool only valid with some distribution, but instead dive into the problem and explain what's under the hood by giving different options to get the desired behaviour in the general Linux case.

Comment: yes, editing the sudoers file or in my case adding a file `/etc/sudoers.d/editor` worked perfectly for changing the editor, thanks :)