# how to use old /etc/passwd file and old home directories after system restore?

Tags: users, accounts

I used Systemback to make a restore points.
Yesterday I was doing something and couldn't make things work properly, so I used Systeback to restore the system to a point in the past. The machine had about 10 people's account(though most of them are doing almost nothing yet..) The problem is, at that restore point, there were only 3 persons. I have the latest /etc/passwd file  and all the 10 peoples' account intact. I tried editing /etc/passwd adding some entries for the added accounts but found users with the new accounts added after the restore point cannot log in. How can I use the /etc/passwd file and old home directories without making new accounts and linking them to old directories?
(ubuntu 16.04.6)

Comment: Beyond the /etc/passwd file, did you ensure the /etc/shadow file also matched?  I don't know, but I suspect some detail may be ignored in the passwd file if it contradicts the shadow file.

Comment: thanks, I soon found I should add the /etc/shadow file. But found the sudoers information should also be updated. Do you know what files contains the sudoers list?

Comment: /etc/sudoers  ; though you should edit with `visudo`  (it checks for errors as the file is ignored from the point an nn error is detected, and thus you can lock yourself out of sudo with a typo)

Comment: Thanks! I edited /etc/sudoers and it just works fine. Please make your response an answer then I'll choose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some password info is also stored in `/etc/shadow`, so entries in that file may also need to be made (or that file restored; not just `/etc/passwd`)

In comments I was also asked about the location of *sudoers* file; it's `/etc/sudoers`.  It's risky to edit that file directly (which I do on occasion anyway) as when it's read, if an error is detected it's treated as the EOF (*end-of-file*) which means any users with rights from that line on in file are ignored which can stop them using `sudo`. The command `visudo` command edits the file (using your default editor) and checks for errors before exit.

Comment: thanks! I once used visudo but the editor was something that I am not familiar with, so I made a mistake (by joining some lines..) and sudo didn't work. So I had to do `su` (as root) and correct the /etc/sudoers file. I thinks using visudo is trickier. :)

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/539243/how-to-change-visudo-editor-from-nano-to-vim  (ie. `visudo` to me makes perfect because I prefer `vim` being the modern version of `vi`) but you can change $EDITOR to something more to your tastes.